C# Unrecognized Escape Sequence using internal server name
Took a quick look and don't see this question answered for my specific issue.  I've got an internal server; xyz2112.internal.rush.com.  There is a directory we copy our files to on this server names Cygnus.  I need to write code to open any file located here, whether it's a .doc, .jpg, .xls, etc...
So, I have this code which I've cannibalized from various parts of the intarwebz:
if (usr.Production == true)
{
    strURL = "\\\\xyz2112.internal.rush.com/Cygnus/" + ((Label)GridView_Attachments.Rows[index].FindControl("Question_Attachments")).Text;
}

new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"" + strURL + "")
    {
        UseShellExecute = true
    }
}.Start();

It doesn't seem to work.  When I step through the code, strURL = "\\xyz2112.internal.rush.com/Cygnus/C35392_10_24_2024_10_15_23 AM_10_Steps.jpg".  If I use a "\" instead of a "/" between the server and folder names, I get an "Unrecognized escape sequence" error. I think it's not escaping the quotations correctly?  I'm not really sure.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

What do you expect @"" + strURL + "" to do, and why? It's saying "concatenate strUrl with an empty string, and then concatenate another empty string on the result". In other words, you still end up with strUrl. The real question IMO is what string value you need to pass to the ProcessStartInfo constructor. If you actually need four backslashes in that value, then you can either use a verbatim string literal a few lines earlier, or double them there (so you have eight backslashes) or pass in strUrl.Replace(@"\", "\\") to do the escapgin.

@JonSkeet - I think I want to pass \xyz2112.internal.rush.com\Cygnus\C35392_10_24_2024_10_15_23 AM_10_Steps.jpg to ProcessStartInfo, as that seems to work if I just open a web browser and type it in

So if you want backslashes, why have you included forward-slashes in the string? It looks like you do know how to escape backslashes (as you've done it at the start) so why not do the same thing later? I'd suggest just using a verbatim string literal with exactly what you want though: strURL = @"\\xyz2112.internal.rush.com\Cygnus\" + ...

The problem is, there are 3 different server names, depending on the environment.  So that has to remain a variable

It's very hard to answer a question when we don't know all the requirements beforehand. Can you at least try what I've suggested there? If that works, I'd suggest rewriting the question so it can actually be answered in a way which is unlikely to prompt "Oh, but I have another requirement that this doesn't solve..." (Note that I've only changed how the variable is initialized anyway, so I'm not sure I follow why my suggestion would be a problem...)

You escape the beginning \\\\.  Why don't you escape the middle?  `\\xyz2112.internal.rush.com\Cygnus\

After some trial and error, this worked:
strURL = "\\\\xyz2112.internal.rush.com\\Cygnus\\" + ((Label)GridView_Attachments.Rows[index].FindControl("Question_Attachments")).Text;

Hopefully this helps someone else who might be trying to do the same thing.
